# d3js circle turns black - String is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had an error with my d3 chart that sometimes at loading it give me this error "used JS COnsole":

> uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

here is the code

```
var margin = { top: 290, right: 360, bottom: 290, left: 360 },
                            radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 10;

                    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

                    var y = d3.scale.linear()
                        .range([0, radius]);

                    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                        .domain(["foo", "bdo", "baz"])
                        .range(colorbrewer.Spectral[8]);

                    var svg = d3.select("#chart2").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", '100%')
                        .attr("height", '100%')
                        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + Math.min(margin.left + margin.right, margin.top + margin.bottom) + ' ' + Math.min(margin.left + margin.right, margin.top + margin.bottom))
                        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
                        .append("g")
                            .attr("id", "container")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(margin.left + margin.right, margin.top + margin.bottom) / 2 + "," + Math.min(margin.left + margin.right, margin.top + margin.bottom) / 2 + ")");

                    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
                        .value(function (d) { return d.size; });

                    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .startAngle(function (d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
                        .endAngle(function (d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
                        // lw 3'erna al y(d.y) we 2smnaha 3la 2 he3'er al radius le al first level
                        .innerRadius(function (d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
                        .outerRadius(function (d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });


                    d3.json("@Html.Raw( Url.Action("GetD3_JSON", "Account", new { type=ViewBag.type, year=ViewBag.CurrentYear, month=ViewBag.CurrentMonth, day=ViewBag.CurrentDay, project=ViewBag.ProjectGUID, code = (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Income") ? 1 : (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Expenses") ? -1 : 0 }) )", function (error, root) {
                        // Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
                        // Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
                        // and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.
                        partition
                            .value(function (d) { return d.size; })
                            .nodes(root)
                            .forEach(function (d) {
                                d._children = d.children;
                                d.sum = d.value;
                            });

                        // Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
                        partition
                            .children(function (d, depth) { return depth < 2 ? d._children : null; })
                            .value(function (d) { return d.sum; });

                        var g = svg.selectAll("g")
                            .data(partition.nodes(root))
                            .enter().append("g");

                        var path = g.append("path")
                          .attr("d", arc)
                          .style("fill", function (d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
                          .on("click", click)
                          .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                              tooltip.show([d3.event.clientX, d3.event.clientY], '<div>' + d.name + '</div><div>' + d.value + '</div>')
                          })
                          .on('mouseout', function () {
                              tooltip.cleanup()
                          })
                          .each(stash);


                        // Define the legeneds
                        var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
                          .attr("class", "legend")
                          .attr("width", radius)
                          .attr("height", radius)
                          .selectAll("g")
                          .data(partition.nodes(root))
                          .enter().append("g")
                          .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

                        legend.append("rect")
                          .attr("width", 18)
                          .attr("height", 18)
                          .style("fill", function (d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
                          .on("click", click);

                        legend.append("text")
                          .attr("x", 24)
                          .attr("y", 9)
                          .attr("dy", ".35em")
                          .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

                        // Define Labels on the arcs
                        var text = g.append("text")
                        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
                        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
                        .attr("x", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
                        .attr("dx", "6") // margin
                        .attr("display", 'block')
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d.name;
                        })
                        .on("click", click);

                        var center = svg.append("circle")
                          .attr("r", radius / 3)
                          .style("fill", "white")
                          .on("click", click);

                        center.append("title")
                        center.datum(root);

                        function click(d) {
                            // fade out all text elements
                            text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

                            path.transition()
                              .duration(500)
                              .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
                              .each("end", function (e, i) {
                                  // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in d
                                  if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
                                      // get a selection of the associated text element
                                      var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
                                      // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
                                      arcText.transition().duration(250)
                                        .attr("opacity", 1)
                                        .attr("transform", function () { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")" })
                                        .attr("x", function (d) { return y(d.y); });
                                  }
                              });
                        }
                    });

                    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

                    // Interpolate the scales!
                    function arcTween(d) {
                        var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
                            yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
                            yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y * radius]);
                        return function (d, i) {
                            return i
                                ? function (t) { return arc(d); }
                                : function (t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
                        };
                    }

                    function computeTextRotation(d) {
                        return (x(d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180;
                    }

                    // Stash the old values for transition.
                    function stash(d) {
                        d.x0 = d.x;
                        d.dx0 = d.dx;
                    }

                    /*****
                     * A no frills tooltip implementation.
                     *****/

                    (function () {

                        var tooltip = window.tooltip = {}

                        tooltip.show = function (pos, content, gravity, dist, parentContainer, classes) {

                            var container = d3.select('body').selectAll('.tooltip').data([1])

                            container.enter().append('div').attr('class', 'tooltip ' + (classes ? classes : 'xy-tooltip'))

                            container.html(content)

                            gravity = gravity || 'n'
                            dist = dist || 20

                            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

                            var height = parseInt(container[0][0].offsetHeight)
                              , width = parseInt(container[0][0].offsetWidth)
                              , windowWidth = window.innerWidth
                              , windowHeight = window.innerHeight
                              , scrollTop = body.scrollTop
                              , scrollLeft = body.scrollLeft
                              , left = 0
                              , top = 0


                            switch (gravity) {
                                case 'e':
                                    left = pos[0] - width - dist
                                    top = pos[1] - (height / 2)
                                    if (left < scrollLeft) left = pos[0] + dist
                                    if (top < scrollTop) top = scrollTop + 5
                                    if (top + height > scrollTop + windowHeight) top = scrollTop - height - 5
                                    break
                                case 'w':
                                    left = pos[0] + dist
                                    top = pos[1] - (height / 2)
                                    if (left + width > windowWidth) left = pos[0] - width - dist
                                    if (top < scrollTop) top = scrollTop + 5
                                    if (top + height > scrollTop + windowHeight) top = scrollTop - height - 5
                                    break
                                case 's':
                                    left = pos[0] - (width / 2)
                                    top = pos[1] + dist
                                    if (left < scrollLeft) left = scrollLeft + 5
                                    if (left + width > windowWidth) left = windowWidth - width - 5
                                    if (top + height > scrollTop + windowHeight) top = pos[1] - height - dist
                                    break
                                case 'n':
                                    left = pos[0] - (width / 2)
                                    top = pos[1] - height - dist
                                    if (left < scrollLeft) left = scrollLeft + 5
                                    if (left + width > windowWidth) left = windowWidth - width - 5
                                    if (scrollTop > top) top = pos[1] + 20
                                    break
                            }


                            container.style('left', left + 'px')
                            container.style('top', top + 'px')

                            return container
                        }

                        tooltip.cleanup = function () {
                            // Find the tooltips, mark them for removal by this class (so other tooltip functions won't find it)
                            var tooltips = d3.selectAll('.tooltip').attr('class', 'tooltip-pending-removal').transition().duration(250).style('opacity', 0).remove()

                        }
                    })()
```

the error with this line

```
       .style("fill", function (d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
```

but i fixed it by fixing the structure of the json file "ignore the arabic fonts"

```
    {
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "المصاريف",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Expense_1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "<غير مصنف>",
              "size": 500.0000
            },
            {
              "name": "ExpSubCat1_1",
              "size": 5772.0000
            },
            {
              "name": "ExpSubCat1_2",
              "size": 5471.0000
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "ffffff",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "<غير مصنف>",
              "size": 19.0000
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "الدخل",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ffff",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "<غير مصنف>",
              "size": 10334.0000
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Income_1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "IncSubCat1_1",
              "size": 6371.0000
            },
            {
              "name": "<غير مصنف>",
              "size": 11211.0000
            },
            {
              "name": "IncSubCat1_2",
              "size": 7160.0000
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Income_2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "<غير مصنف>",
              "size": 39.0000
            },
            {
              "name": "IncSubCat2_2",
              "size": 7256.0000
            },
            {
              "name": "IncSubCat2_1",
              "size": 583090.0000
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "الربح",
      "size": 601700.0000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure you load d3.js library before your script

Comment: Yea i'm sure that its loaded before my script i put it in the head of each page!

Comment: So you fixed the error?

Comment: first time i fixed another error in the same line that were telling me that name is unknown type!
but now different error in the same line! but it says uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: the function of the color is the problem i used this function and it is working good
.style("fill",function() {
    return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)";
    })